# Filtering an annotation or count in Django's ORM

Tags: django, orm

I'm trying to find all blogs that have at least 2 published entries.

```
from django.db import models as Count, db_models

class Blog(db_models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Entry(db_models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    is_published = models.BooleanField()
```

I can find all blogs with at least two entries using.

```
Blog.objects.annotate(entries=Count('entry')).filter(entries__gte=2)
```

But how can I can exclude all non-published entries from the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Blog.objects.exclude(entry__is_published=False).annotate(entries=Count('entry')).filter(entries__gte=2)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this will also exclude blogs with two or more published entries and one non-published? I think best solution here would be to use `extra` -> ``Blog.objects.extra(select={'published_entry_count': "select count(*) from `entry` where is_published = 1 and `entry`.`blog_id` = `blog`.`id`"}).filter(published_entry_count__gte=2)``

Comment: Wasn't quite right when I tried to test it, seems like `.filter` can't handle `.extra` annotated fields. Check my answer to see how this can be surrounded.

Answer (score 0):

**@ruddra** answer is nice, but this way you will also exclude blogs with single non-published entry and more than two published entries. Unfortunately the best solution i can think of is to use django's [`.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

```
Blog.objects.extra(
    #the select is optional
    #if u need the blog's published entry count
    select={
        'published_entry_count': "select count(*) from `entry` where `is_published` = 1 and `entry`.`blog_id` = `blog`.`id`"
    },
    where=["(select count(*) from `entry` where `is_published` = 1 and `entry`.`blog_id` = `blog`.`id`) >= 2"]
)
```